# JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC in java swing application

Tags: java, encryption

I am creating a swing based application in Java which uses some encryption technique. But 
javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES", "BC") gives exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
        at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..)
        at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: This usually means you've done something wrong with packaging of the classes/jars and/or the classpath. You can't extract the BC classes from their jar and put them in another jar.

Comment: Check you classpath, maybe you have several different versions of BouncyCastle JARs as it happened to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To expand on the comment from GregS, all JCE provider JARs must be signed before they will be trusted by your Java runtime.

BouncyCastle dutifully supplies signed JARs that will work without a problem. However, if you extract class files from this JAR, or recompile the source, it will remove the signature and cause Java to reject the code.

See this related SO question: [How to sign a custom JCE security provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756801/how-to-sign-a-custom-jce-security-provider)

Comment: I did not extract or recompile the jar file, I only download bcprov-jdk14 and bcpkix-jdk14 from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/ ; however, it does not work for me!

Comment: Use OpenJDK. It does not require the JCE provider to be signed.

Answer (score 56):

1. edit `jre\lib\security\java.security`
2. add `security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`
3. copy `bc*.jar` to `jre\lib\ext`

Comment: This worked great for me! I was using jython, even though I specified the jar files directly (did not extract class files separately), I got the exception stated. Possibly jython extracts it. Great solution. Thanks!

Comment: It does not work for me?
I did these two steps; however, I keep getting this error. any Help please

Comment: For more information: `bc*.jar` means the BouncyCastle's jar file that can be download from web. For me, it's `bcprov-jdk15-140.jar`

Comment: does anything else need to be done? for example restart of Java App or restart of Operating System?

Comment: Followed above steps and worked great for me. Additionally I uncommented `java.security=unlimited` line. I am on JRE version "1.8.0_271".

Comment: This worked for my exception in Grails Application as well. However, I already had this line:
`security.provider.10=apple.security.AppleProvider`
which I changed into this:
`security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`

Will it affect any other modules / workflow?

Answer (score 4):

For those finding this issue but actually using `SpongyCastle`, it might be interesting to know that on Android there is no such signature test and for your tests you can use SpongyCastle via the openJDK-8 as that doesn't care about signatures neither.

For reference, with SpongyCastle the error reads:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider SC
```

More information in [this issue](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle-old/issues/13)

Answer (score 1):

We have been suffering with the same issue for a few weeks and had tried a lot of the suggested steps to no avail. Providing our solution below so others don't have to suffer like we did!

We were attempting to use bcprov-ext-jdk15on-162.jar, added to classpath, included in JBoss lib directories, bundled with WAR, marked as provided and added to JBoss /lib directories but no luck.

In the end, we tried different versions of bouncycastle and found a less recent version who's signature could be verified by our particular Java version's jarsigner (1.5X).

Despite the jar's signature being verifiable by our Java version, when the .jar is packaged into a WAR the signature was invalidated somehow by JBoss.

In the end, the solution for us was to;

```
1. Add bouncycastle jar to JBoss classpath
2. Add 'org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider' to 'java.security' providers
3. Mark bouncycastle in your WAR as a 'provided' dependency
```

Once we had a version of the .jar on our classpath and were sure that our WAR was not packaging it in we were golden.

The issue seems to be tightly coupled to whatever Java/JBoss version you happen to be using. So if this solution does not work for you I would suggest to test different versions of bouncycastle with

```
jarsigner -verify <bouncycastle.jar>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of solutions to this problem but unfortunately nobody talks about the causing issue.

If you are generating an executable jar that has BC.jar in it(in form of any dependency) than this issue would occur if below condition matches:

1. Generating jar via eclipse's export option i.e. Export-> Runnable Jar File -> Libary Handling {extract required libraries into generated Jar}-> FINISH

Boom, now you have landed into trouble and you will face an error i.e. **JCE can't authenticate the provider BC**

The reason for above problem is, when you create a jar with option 1 than you are actually unpacking the BouncyCastle jar again that violates the security assosiated with BC. So, whenever you run it again java validates it and finds current BC.jar in your assosiated jar has an error.

So, guys make sure what you are doing is justified because by changing the JDK's security data that will make it work but not for everyone.

How to make it work?{This will work on local/personal machine only,not on every machine }

1. edit jre\lib\security\java.security file
2. add security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
3. copy bc*.jar to jre\lib\ext

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was `bcprov-ext-jdk16.jar` was being discarded by `sbt assembly`.

```
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/license/LICENSE.bouncycastle.txt' with strategy 'discard'
..
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/maven/org.jasypt/jasypt/pom.properties' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/maven/org.jasypt/jasypt/pom.xml' with strategy 'discard'
..
```

So I ended up using the `bouncycastle.jar` [from `-classpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413058/432903) as below,

```
java -Denvironment=dev -cp chat-server.jar:/Users/prayagupd/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk16/jars/bcprov-ext-jdk16-1.46.jar com.chat.server.ChatServer
```

**What also works is putting the bouncycastle.jar to `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`,**

```
cp /Users/prayagupd/.ivy2/cache/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk16/jars/bcprov-ext-jdk16-1.46.jar $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/

$ ls -l $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/
total 55208
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   1887089 May  7 21:22 bcprov-ext-jdk16-1.46.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel   3860502 Sep  5  2017 cldrdata.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel      8286 Sep  5  2017 dnsns.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel     44516 Sep  5  2017 jaccess.jar
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  wheel  18610276 Sep  5  2017 jfxrt.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel   1179093 Sep  5  2017 localedata.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel      1269 Sep  5  2017 meta-index
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel   2022735 Sep  5  2017 nashorn.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel     41672 Sep  5  2017 sunec.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel    274148 Sep  5  2017 sunjce_provider.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel    248726 Sep  5  2017 sunpkcs11.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  wheel     68924 Sep  5  2017 zipfs.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: instead of modifying java.security and copying jar to \jre\lib\ext, below steps resolved my issue as well.

1. add Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()) in your class.
2. add provided scope to bcprov.*.jar dependency in pom.xml.
3. put bcprov.*.jar to your specific folder(e.g: \lib), then refer it when run the project.

Comment: I tried with this approach but didn't work for me. I think reason was if you use jar in other project. BC prov error occurs there with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Open JDK and the issue will disappear. I used openJDK21

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).