# Bouncy Castle throws SecurityException when run from jar assembled with dependencies by maven

Tags: maven, bouncycastle

I used the maven assembly plugin to package my program in a jar-with-dependencies (a non execuatable jar that includes my program plus all classes extracted from the jars it depends on). When I make a call to Bouncy Castle to encrypt file it throws and exception for which the root cause is this:

> java.util.jar.JarException: file:Foo.jar has unsigned entries

Will signing my jar solve the problems? Is there any way to make Bouncy Castle skip the check for unsigned classes? If I do need to sign it can I get maven to do it automatically when I build the jar?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JCE is one source for these types of errors. In Java 8, the error is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

The problem is that extracting the files using something like Maven shade can break the signature required by JCE ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13726570/5786226)).

The solution is to use something like the [executable maven packer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44226166/5786226) that creates a single jar that also preserves the BouncyCastle jar file intact.