# Error when generating runnable jar on maven but not on Eclipse using signed jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, bouncycastle, executable-jar

I have created an encrypting application with signed jars (BouncyCastle). When I package the jar as runnable jar on maven using maven-shade-plugin and run it it causes an error:

"JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC"

But when I export it on eclipse as runnable jar and run it, it doesn't cause an error. Why is that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721579/jce-cannot-authenticate-the-provider-bc-in-java-swing-application

Comment: I know but why does it work when I export it as runnable jar on eclipse?