# "JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC" when using sshj

Tags: java, spring, maven, bouncycastle, sshj

I am trying to use the [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) library to create an SFTP client in an existing project of my company. However if I create the `SSHClient` instance I get the error message:

```
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils - Registration of Security Provider 'org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider' unexpectedly failed
java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:118)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:270)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils.registerSecurityProvider(SecurityUtils.java:88)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils.register(SecurityUtils.java:267)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils.isBouncyCastleRegistered(SecurityUtils.java:245)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig.<init>(DefaultConfig.java:79)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.<init>(SSHClient.java:134)
[... junit stacktrace ...]
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: Class is on the bootclasspath
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:286)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:164)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:190)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:114)
    ... 40 more
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils - BouncyCastle not registered, using the default JCE provider
[main] INFO net.schmizz.sshj.transport.random.JCERandom - Creating new SecureRandom.
```

The application uses maven to include dependencies and I added it like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hierynomus</groupId>
  <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
  <version>0.27.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The sshj library includes the bouncycastle (BC) dependencies to `bcpkix-jdk15on` v1.60 and `bcprov-jdk15on` v1.60 and I've tried the following solutions:

1. Add the BC provider on my own, include the sshj and BC JARs directly as library and use the provided scope in maven as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50813383/6419859). The provider is then added correctly but still fails with the error message from above.
2. Place the BC JARs in the `jre/lib/ext` folder.
3. Modify the java.security file as stated [here](https://hamroblog-sristi.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-fix-javalangsecurityexception.html).
4. Check if there is another BC version on the classpath as stated [here](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/JCE-unable-to-authenticate-BC-td1465863.html).

**However** if I create a fresh project and include sshj everything is working just fine and as expected. I compared the commands which execute my junit test which crates the SSHClient and in both projects I can find the sshj JAR and the BC JARs included in the `-classpath`.

I am fairly new to maven and spring so I might be missing something obviously why everything is fine in a fresh project and not in the existing one, but I just can't figure it out.

If you need any more information I will gladly provide them!

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721579/jce-cannot-authenticate-the-provider-bc-in-java-swing-application/13726570#13726570  and try to edit your java.security as the comments said

Comment: Thanks for the hint @sam3131, but my point 3. is, that I already tried to edit the java.security file. Moreover I am not extracting or recompiling the BC JARs but just try to use them. So the signature shouldn't be touched in any way afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 classpaths in Java, the `bootclasspath` and the regular `classpath`. The bootclasspath is where `java.*` and `javax.*` are located (jre/lib/rt.jar). But because that is not loaded by the system classloader, it is not supported to drop signed/verified jars in there. You need to ensure that the BouncyCastle jars are on the regular classpath (as specified using the `-classpath` option in the JRE/JDK

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it actually lead me to the right point. I was using PowerMock for testing my class and `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` was causing the error for loading the classes on the bootclasspath.