# How to fix org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: Unable to create OpenSSL PBDKF: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC error in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, bouncycastle

I am using Bouncy Castle Provider downloaded from https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html. I am packaging the executable jar as an .exe file using [jar2exe](https://www.jar2exe.com/) The bouncy castle jar files are in same folder as exe file. They are not inside executable jar. Will adding source code for these files to main project help?

```
2023-05-27 22:18:10:724 [ERROR] [main:ID=1]:[OpcUaServerServiceImpl.java:297] org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: Unable to create OpenSSL PBDKF: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.getKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.getKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.crypt(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcePEMEncryptorBuilder$1.encrypt(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.createPemObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.prosysopc.ua.stack.transport.security.BcCertificateProvider.writePrivateKey(SourceFile:271)
    at com.prosysopc.ua.stack.utils.CertificateUtils.writePrivateKey(SourceFile:1080)
    at com.prosysopc.ua.stack.utils.CertificateUtils.writePrivateKey(SourceFile:1064)
    at com.prosysopc.ua.stack.transport.security.PrivKey.save(SourceFile:380)
    at com.prosysopc.ua.ApplicationIdentity.saveCertificate(SourceFile:1358)
    at com.prosysopc.ua.ApplicationIdentity.loadOrCreateIssuerCertificate(SourceFile:872)
    at opcuaserver.services.OpcUaServerServiceImpl.initialize(OpcUaServerServiceImpl.java:592)
    at opcuaserver.services.OpcUaServerServiceImpl.startServer(OpcUaServerServiceImpl.java:276)
    at opcuaserver.OpcUaServerApplication.run(OpcUaServerApplication.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at opcuaserver.OpcUaServerApplication.main(OpcUaServerApplication.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:131)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:208)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.NamedJcaJceHelper.createSecretKeyFactory(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.getKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.getKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.PEMUtilities.crypt(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcePEMEncryptorBuilder$1.encrypt(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.createPemObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC in java swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721579/jce-cannot-authenticate-the-provider-bc-in-java-swing-application)