# Can use a self-sign certificate to sign JCE provider(for testing purpose)

Tags: java, jce

I wrote a new provider and also a application to test it.

JCE only accepted a signed provider according this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#Step62).

I didn't have a certificate from an entity trusted by JCA, so i wonder can i use a self-sign certificate to sign this new provider.

I followed this [article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/java-add-certificate-ca-store/?fb=zh-cn) to add my certificate to JDK's cacerts. Then used this 
certificate to sign the provider jar file.

But i still got this Exception：

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider Tang
  at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
  at SSLServer.<init>(SSLServer.java:48)
  at SSLServer.main(SSLServer.java:156)
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: Cannot parse file:/D:/Develop/tang.jar
  at javax.crypto.SunJCE_c.a(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.b(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..)
  ... 4 more
```

My question is only a certificate from an entity trusted by JCA can sign JCE provider jar file, anyother java code-signing certificate, like comodo or self-siged, can't？

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sign a custom JCE security provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756801/how-to-sign-a-custom-jce-security-provider)

Comment: It seems solve my problem. Thanks.